# Docusign Connect Settings

Tags: docusignapi

I have the following settings in Demo Docusign Connect to use the Soap API

```
URL to publish to  https://demo.docusign.net
Name DocusignConnect
Use Soap Interface (check box checked)
```

Is there more configuration required. I am  not able to connect to the API service using Soap Client calls

The Docusign Code is as follows

```
public APIServiceSoap getAPI() {

        DocusignAPICredentials apiCreds = new DocusignAPICredentials();
        apiCreds.setAccountId(accountId);
        apiCreds.setUserId(username);
        apiCreds.setIntegratorsKey(integratorKey);
        apiCreds.setPassword(password);
        apiCreds.setUserEmail(email);
        apiCreds.setDocusignWebserviceEndpoint(credentialURL);

        DocusignWebserviceFactory wsFactory = new DocusignWebserviceFactory();
        wsFactory.setEmail(apiCreds.getUserEmail());
        wsFactory.setIntegratorsId(apiCreds.getIntegratorsKey());
        wsFactory.setUserId(apiCreds.getUserId());

        return wsFactory.setupClient(apiCreds.getDocusignWebserviceEndpoint()).authorizeAPI(apiCreds);
    }
```

The file DocuSignWebServiceFactory and DocuSignApiCredentials are taken from the Github sample example of Connect located at https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-SOAP-SDK
Simple test to validate the code

```
@Test
    public void testLogin() {

        APIServiceSoap serviceSoap = utils.getAPI();

        serviceSoap.voidEnvelope("dhfafgajf", "No Reason");
    }
```

The Error I keep getting is this

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not write attachments.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentOutInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:411)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:137)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.voidEnvelope(Unknown Source)
    at com.cargill.crm.docservices.docusign.workflow.LoginTest.testLogin(LoginTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringTestMethod.invoke(SpringTestMethod.java:198)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(SpringMethodRoadie.java:274)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$2.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:207)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: demo.docusign.net
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:200)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:951)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1296)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1252)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentSerializer.writeProlog(AttachmentSerializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentOutInterceptor.java:72)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Please remember to upvote all useful answers and "check" the answer that best solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DocuSign connect](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect) calls *your* app. This pattern is often called a "[web hook](https://webhooks.pbworks.com/w/page/13385124/FrontPage)"

You should enter the url for your "receiving app" into the Connect configuration page. Your url needs to be accessible from the public internet since the DocuSign.net platform will be calling your app.

**Re: "I am not able to connect to the API service using Soap Client calls"**

That's the way it should be. You don't connect to the DocuSign Connect service, it connects to your application.

Hope this helps. Please ask additional questions as you develop your application.

**Added**

DocuSign has two different SOAP APIs. The first is the [SOAP API](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm) for sending documents to be signed. This API includes many other services too. Its WSDL is hosted at demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx

This is a standard SOAP service. Your app calls the API.

The other API is [DocuSign Connect](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/connect-guide.pdf). It is **not** an API that you call. It is a "Web hook API." Your software does **not** make calls to this type of API. Instead, you register a URL with the Connect service and **it calls you.**

When you create a DocuSign Connect configuration and register your url, you can also choose to have DocuSign Connect make a SOAP call your listener or a more plain HTTPS call.

If you choose SOAP, then your application acts as a SOAP service and the WSDL would be published by **you.** (In reality, there is no need for you to make a WSDL for your listener service. But you can if you want to.)

**Re: I'm behind a proxy**

This is an issue. In order for the DocuSign Connect service to call your listener application, your app needs to be visible on the public internet. If your software is behind a gateway/firewall/proxy then you need to open up a "pinhole" so DocuSign Connect can reach your listener application.

Comment: I am not using the publish feature , I am trying to access the SOAP API, Does this answer still applies in that case

Comment: Are you trying to send an envelope for signing, or do you want status updates about the envelopes you have sent? Connect is for the latter, and that is what my answer refers to.

Comment: I want the latter, but I am building a Rest Service which will call the Connect Soap services, Rest Endpoints are going to be used by the UI team. We have certain workflow conditions that Docusign does not support out of the box so to implement the logic I need to use Connect to poll the status of the Envelope.

Comment: One last thing to add is we are behind proxy and I did add that too but still keep getting the same error

Comment: I added to the answer.

Comment: So what is the purpose of the WSDL hosted at  https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx. I should be able to consume this soap service as any other regular soap service

Comment: I added to the answer